# Does “consider” mean “think”?

Tags: word-usage

> 1. I consider cell phones **are** a nuisance.
> 2. I consider cell phones **as** a nuisance.
> 3. Cell phones **are** considered **as** a nuisance.

Which of these sentences are acceptable as standard English?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, *consider* can mean "to think (about)", "to believe" and [more](https://www.google.com/search?q=consider%20definition).

> I consider cellphones a nuisance.
>
> Cellphones are considered a nuisance.

The above are fine. You should lose the "are" in your first sentence, though.